# In recent times which will be the most popular php framework?

Tags: php

I have seen many comparisons about php frameworks but couldn't come to a conclusion on which to start with.

Comment: One of my colleagues uses the Yii framework.  I haven't crossed that bridge yet as I followed a tutorial on creating my own which was more of a learning curve

Comment: try to make same small aplication in all of them and the decision will appear soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start with CodeIgniter. As you become proficient with it, move onto more advanced frameworks like Laravel.
There is a screencast on http://net.tutsplus.com/ on CodeIgniter if I remember correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to add Zend as well ;)

Comment: I really don't know much about Zend tbh. I don't know much about ANY framework. I have heard that codeigniter is easier to learn, hence the recommendation to use it as a stepping stone. Laravel I think is one of the more popular frameworks.

Comment: Laravel and Zend are very common and popular, codeIgniter is the easiest of them to learn due to it's simple nature yet complex background.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that there are too many. I'd say it all boils down to **what you need**. Some frameworks are absolutely swiss-knives with cup-trays but they are more complicated to set up. Other frameworks are barebones (literally, **barebones** is a framework) that just sets you up.

My answer to this would be: all the framworks that are developer-friendly will continue to be the most famous. All of these will cater to different types of projects of different size and complexity. So this question really bears no answer at all TT